# Find the number is mod of which number

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to find the number that gives me the result, here's the equation:

x=y mod z 
x and z can be any prime number
y=?

In this equation, I know values of x and z but I need to find of y too, does anyone has an idea? I have any idea how to do that

Thanks in advance
Any questions just ask!

Comment: Can you elaborate your question, i.e. giving value of x and z, or any additional factors such as if they are co-prime etc?

Comment: Numbers are not specific, it changes when the input changes.

Comment: One solution is that $y=x$.  Another set of solutions would be that $y=x+kz$...

Comment: I downvoted this question because it changed significantly after I wrote an answer.

Comment: @MJD what change? I don't see anything?

Comment: @Sabyasachi http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/703036/revisions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation $$x = y \bmod z$$ means nothing more nor less than $$x-y = kz$$ for some integer $k$.  Your question originally specified $x=5, z=7$, so I will use those as examples.  Plugging in, we get $$5-y = 7k$$ for some integer $k$; rearranging we have $$y = 5-7k$$ for some integer $k$.  This is all the information that is available, so the solution for $y$ is not unique; $y$ could be any of $\ldots, -9, -2, 5, 12, 19,\ldots$.

Comment: why community wiki?

Comment: @Sabyasachi Because points aren't important.

Comment: Points aren't important $\ne$ always use community wiki. or do you? Yes I just abused $\LaTeX$

Answer (score 0):

$x\equiv y \pmod{z}$ means that $z$ divides the difference $y-x$.  If you know $x,y$, then $z$ can be any divisor of their difference.